# Opencv2.1 did not start in Win7

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, opencv

I am using VS2010 and opencv2.1. Under Win7, the sample programme is below:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <highgui.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])

{

        IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("funny-pictures-cat-goes-pew.jpg");
        cvNamedWindow("Image:",1);
        cvShowImage("Image:",img); 
        cvWaitKey();
        cvDestroyWindow("Image:");
        cvReleaseImage(&img);
        return 0;
}
```

The programme failed to start.  I see:

> The application was unable to start correctly(0xc0150002). Click OK to close the application.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the same machine where the compiler is installed?  If not, did you install the VS2010 redistributable runtime along with your own program?

Comment: Don't forget to include the correct version of OpenCV dlls! (If your program is 64-bit, you must use the 64-bit DLLs) `cxcore210.dll, cv210.dll, highgui210.dll`

Comment: it is not the same machine where my vc compiler is installed.

Comment: actually， the libs and dlls was compiled using vc2008 under windows xp.

Comment: maybe installiing the vs2010 redistributable runtime will help, i will have a try

Comment: If you have a main program compiled with VC2010 and libraries compiled with VC2008, you will probably need both the VC2010 runtime and the VC2008 SP1 runtime installed.